# Date value in matDatepicker is not equal with formControl using Reactive Form inAngular 8

Tags: angular

[image]I have a concern regarding matDatepicker in Angular wherein the date (from api) in my formControl using Reactive Forms does not reflect the exact value in matDatepicker. My matDatePicker shows "12/31/2019" while my formControl is "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z".[image] My local timezone is UTC -08:00 Pacific (local computer) while my webservice server timezone and mySQL Database is UTC-00:00. I noticed that Angular applies the offset value from my local timezone. What can I do to adjust it to reflect the exact value from my database?

Reactive form:

```
this.currencyRatesArray = <FormArray>this.currencyForm.get('currencyRates');
      for (const currencyRate of _currency.currencyRates) {
        const grp = this.formBuilder.group({
          id: [currencyRate.id],
          effectiveDateFrom: [new Date(currencyRate.effectiveDateFrom), Validators.required],
          effectiveDateTo: [new Date(currencyRate.effectiveDateTo), Validators.required],
          currencyRate: [currencyRate.currencyRate, Validators.required],
          active: [currencyRate.active, Validators.required],
        });
        this.currencyRatesArray.push(grp);
        this.currencyForm.setControl('currencyRates', this.currencyRatesArray);
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(
          (this.currencyForm.get('currencyRates') as FormArray).controls);
      }
```

JSON String from Webservice

```
"currencyRates": [
{
  "id": "6ea84267-5a47-4aeb-afac-7eee65ff95ec",
  "effectiveDateFrom": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "effectiveDateTo": "2020-12-31T00:00:00.000Z",
  "currencyRate": 1,
  "active": true
}
```

]

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the issue few days back. Angular material date picker by default uses `DatePipe` to manipulate `date` variables. Which is creating the issue. 
I have fixed is using `moment.js` in my app. So install `moment.js`.

Please follow the code it might help you.

```
npm I moment // install this

import * as moment from 'moment'; // include this in your ts file

effectiveDateFrom: [moment(currencyRate.effectiveDateFrom), Validators.required],
effectiveDateTo: [moment(currencyRate.effectiveDateTo), Validators.required],
```

Also while you save use moment as well for your DB.

```
const saveDate = moment(toDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

> here I choose to save the date in YYYY-MM-DD for my purpose you can change though. But moment.js will surely help you in this situation.

Comment: Hi sibabrat swain, appreciate your suggestion however, I've lost the value of matatePicker when I changed it to "effectiveDateFrom: [moment(currencyRate.effectiveDateFrom), Validators.required],
              effectiveDateTo: [moment(currencyRate.effectiveDateTo), Validators.required]". The values did not fetch to matDatePicker. I also attached the screenshot. Thank you

Comment: Please Check by removing the moment and take the date directly but make sure while you send data to save api format it using moment.`const saveDate = moment(toDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')` do let me know and also you can add this to stackblitz if you want some direct solution to it.